# Does there exist a two-generated simple non-abelian group with specific properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, finitely-generated, simple-groups

> Does there exist a simple non-abelian 2-generated group $G$ and two elements $a, b \in G$, such that $\langle \{a, b\} \rangle = G$, $a^2 =1$ and $\forall c, d \in G$ $\langle \{c^{-1}bc, d^{-1}bd \} \rangle \neq G$?

We know that every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group acting on $G$ by Cayley's theorem .

So, if our example is finite then we can use the fact that if $G$ is a non-abelian finite, simple group of order $>2$ and $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, then $G$ must be a subgroup of $A_n$.

However, the group in question is not necessarily finite.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356063/about-simple-non-abelian-2-generated-group

Answer (score 0):

No. Note that $\langle b ,a^{-1}ba \rangle$ is normalized by $b$, and by $a$. Hence 
$\langle b, a^{-1}ba \rangle$ is normalized by $\langle a,b \rangle = G$. Since $G$ is simple non-Abelian, $G = \langle b, a^{-1}ba \rangle .$also we must show why $⟨b,a^{−1}ba⟩≠{1}$ ? ( because  $b≠1$)

Comment: Are you posting this as a full answer to the question, or are there bits which you still don't understand from the comments below the [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/356065/35478)?